# How to integrate news article / comments with Firebase?

Tags: android, wordpress, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've been trying to create an app that follows these three steps:

1. Register via Facebook
2. Create new user in Firebase database
3. Allow registered users to see news articles and comment

I am stuck on #3. I'm not sure this is efficient, but I want to post articles on a site such as Wordpress or whatever and parse the JSON to the app. However, I do not know how to implement the comments.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could have, in the Firebase realtime DB, a structure like:

```
[root]    
    -[article_urls]
        -[comments]
            -[comment_id]
                -[content]->value
                -[user_id]->value
```

etc.
The interesting bit of the Firebase database documentation would be:

- [best practice firebase database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data#best_practices_for_data_structure): ie, keep your data flat
- [How to add data to a list in Firebase database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/save-data#append_to_a_list_of_data): When you add a new comment to an article you are actually adding it to a list